# A "like" button similar to one in INSTAGRAM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So the thing is I am working on something sort of an e-commerce website and here users get to "like" or "unlike" the items they have bought. 
I was looking for a button as the one in INSTAGRAM - the heart shape when clicked turns red and shows a slight animation during the transition.

I am using a glyphicon in Bootstrap, the smiley one, and well using `background-color:yellow;` to the glyphicon changes the color of the square inside which the icon resides.

I am not very great at jquery and stuff so I was hoping to achieve this in CSS if its even possible. OR should I go with two different images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plane css, persistens changes - means you click somethin, it changes it apperance and never changes back - are not possible.
What you could do in css would be to do the effect on hover, but it would disappear when your mouse stops hovering the "heart".
I would really recommend using jQuery, its simple to use and everyone makes the first step sometimes, you wont regret having a bit of experience with it.

In jQuery you could apply a `.click()` event to your like button and if it gets triggered, use `.animate()` to enlarge it and change its background-color in a lets say 200ms transition and then do the enlargement in reverse, also with `animate()`.

Thats the prettiest and easiest way to do it, if you want to create an e-commerce like site which HAS to attract people by its appearance you wont be ably to do it properly without jQuery anyway.

Comment: Well thanks.. So I go with jquery but just a little issue I have and I feel insanely stupid for asking such a silly question - what should I do about the `background-color` part covering the entire block within its margins while I was looking to color the icon part only? Should I go with two images representing two different states (liked and not liked)?

Comment: Try it, modelling a heart in css will be a bit difficult...